# How to change aspect ratio in fengyuanchen / cropper JS (Crop Avatar)

Tags: jquery, html, aspect-ratio

Hi I would like to use fengyuanchen / cropper  JS (Crop Avatar) in my system. But i can not change aspect ratio for per page. Because aspect ratio is on main.js file with jquery.

So i would like to determinite apect ratio in index.html

Here is codes

main.js (PS: Aspect Ratio is on line 201.)

```js
(function (factory) {
  if (typeof define === 'function' && define.amd) {
    // AMD. Register as anonymous module.
    define(['jquery'], factory);
  } else if (typeof exports === 'object') {
    // Node / CommonJS
    factory(require('jquery'));
  } else {
    // Browser globals.
    factory(jQuery);
  }
})(function ($) {

  'use strict';

  var console = window.console || { log: function () {} };

  function CropAvatar($element) {
    this.$container = $element;

    this.$avatarView = this.$container.find('.avatar-view');
    this.$avatar = this.$avatarView.find('img');
    this.$avatarModal = this.$container.find('#avatar-modal');
    this.$loading = this.$container.find('.loading');

    this.$avatarForm = this.$avatarModal.find('.avatar-form');
    this.$avatarUpload = this.$avatarForm.find('.avatar-upload');
    this.$avatarSrc = this.$avatarForm.find('.avatar-src');
    this.$avatarData = this.$avatarForm.find('.avatar-data');
    this.$avatarInput = this.$avatarForm.find('.avatar-input');
    this.$avatarSave = this.$avatarForm.find('.avatar-save');
    this.$avatarBtns = this.$avatarForm.find('.avatar-btns');

    this.$avatarWrapper = this.$avatarModal.find('.avatar-wrapper');
    this.$avatarPreview = this.$avatarModal.find('.avatar-preview');

    this.init();
  }

  CropAvatar.prototype = {
    constructor: CropAvatar,

    support: {
      fileList: !!$('<input type="file">').prop('files'),
      blobURLs: !!window.URL && URL.createObjectURL,
      formData: !!window.FormData
    },

    init: function () {
      this.support.datauri = this.support.fileList && this.support.blobURLs;

      if (!this.support.formData) {
        this.initIframe();
      }

      this.initTooltip();
      this.initModal();
      this.addListener();
    },

    addListener: function () {
      this.$avatarView.on('click', $.proxy(this.click, this));
      this.$avatarInput.on('change', $.proxy(this.change, this));
      this.$avatarForm.on('submit', $.proxy(this.submit, this));
      this.$avatarBtns.on('click', $.proxy(this.rotate, this));
    },

    initTooltip: function () {
      this.$avatarView.tooltip({
        placement: 'bottom'
      });
    },

    initModal: function () {
      this.$avatarModal.modal({
        show: false
      });
    },

    initPreview: function () {
      var url = this.$avatar.attr('src');

      this.$avatarPreview.html('<img src="' + url + '">');
    },

    initIframe: function () {
      var target = 'upload-iframe-' + (new Date()).getTime();
      var $iframe = $('<iframe>').attr({
            name: target,
            src: ''
          });
      var _this = this;

      // Ready ifrmae
      $iframe.one('load', function () {

        // respond response
        $iframe.on('load', function () {
          var data;

          try {
            data = $(this).contents().find('body').text();
          } catch (e) {
            console.log(e.message);
          }

          if (data) {
            try {
              data = $.parseJSON(data);
            } catch (e) {
              console.log(e.message);
            }

            _this.submitDone(data);
          } else {
            _this.submitFail('Image upload failed!');
          }

          _this.submitEnd();

        });
      });

      this.$iframe = $iframe;
      this.$avatarForm.attr('target', target).after($iframe.hide());
    },

    click: function () {
      this.$avatarModal.modal('show');
      this.initPreview();
    },

    change: function () {
      var files;
      var file;

      if (this.support.datauri) {
        files = this.$avatarInput.prop('files');

        if (files.length > 0) {
          file = files[0];

          if (this.isImageFile(file)) {
            if (this.url) {
              URL.revokeObjectURL(this.url); // Revoke the old one
            }

            this.url = URL.createObjectURL(file);
            this.startCropper();
          }
        }
      } else {
        file = this.$avatarInput.val();

        if (this.isImageFile(file)) {
          this.syncUpload();
        }
      }
    },

    submit: function () {
      if (!this.$avatarSrc.val() && !this.$avatarInput.val()) {
        return false;
      }

      if (this.support.formData) {
        this.ajaxUpload();
        return false;
      }
    },

    rotate: function (e) {
      var data;

      if (this.active) {
        data = $(e.target).data();

        if (data.method) {
          this.$img.cropper(data.method, data.option);
        }
      }
    },

    isImageFile: function (file) {
      if (file.type) {
        return /^image\/\w+$/.test(file.type);
      } else {
        return /\.(jpg|jpeg|png|gif)$/.test(file);
      }
    },

    startCropper: function () {
      var _this = this;

      if (this.active) {
        this.$img.cropper('replace', this.url);
      } else {
        this.$img = $('<img src="' + this.url + '">');
        this.$avatarWrapper.empty().html(this.$img);
        this.$img.cropper({
          aspectRatio: 1,
          preview: this.$avatarPreview.selector,
          crop: function (e) {
            var json = [
                  '{"x":' + e.x,
                  '"y":' + e.y,
                  '"height":' + e.height,
                  '"width":' + e.width,
                  '"rotate":' + e.rotate + '}'
                ].join();

            _this.$avatarData.val(json);
          }
        });

        this.active = true;
      }

      this.$avatarModal.one('hidden.bs.modal', function () {
        _this.$avatarPreview.empty();
        _this.stopCropper();
      });
    },

    stopCropper: function () {
      if (this.active) {
        this.$img.cropper('destroy');
        this.$img.remove();
        this.active = false;
      }
    },

    ajaxUpload: function () {
      var url = this.$avatarForm.attr('action');
      var data = new FormData(this.$avatarForm[0]);
      var _this = this;

      $.ajax(url, {
        type: 'post',
        data: data,
        dataType: 'json',
        processData: false,
        contentType: false,

        beforeSend: function () {
          _this.submitStart();
        },

        success: function (data) {
          _this.submitDone(data);
        },

        error: function (XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
          _this.submitFail(textStatus || errorThrown);
        },

        complete: function () {
          _this.submitEnd();
        }
      });
    },

    syncUpload: function () {
      this.$avatarSave.click();
    },

    submitStart: function () {
      this.$loading.fadeIn();
    },

    submitDone: function (data) {
      console.log(data);

      if ($.isPlainObject(data) && data.state === 200) {
        if (data.result) {
          this.url = data.result;

          if (this.support.datauri || this.uploaded) {
            this.uploaded = false;
            this.cropDone();
          } else {
            this.uploaded = true;
            this.$avatarSrc.val(this.url);
            this.startCropper();
          }

          this.$avatarInput.val('');
        } else if (data.message) {
          this.alert(data.message);
        }
      } else {
        this.alert('Failed to response');
      }
    },

    submitFail: function (msg) {
      this.alert(msg);
    },

    submitEnd: function () {
      this.$loading.fadeOut();
    },

    cropDone: function () {
      this.$avatarForm.get(0).reset();
      this.$avatar.attr('src', this.url);
      this.stopCropper();
      this.$avatarModal.modal('hide');
    },

    alert: function (msg) {
      var $alert = [
            '<div class="alert alert-danger avatar-alert alert-dismissable">',
              '<button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert">&times;</button>',
              msg,
            '</div>'
          ].join('');

      this.$avatarUpload.after($alert);
    }
  };

  $(function () {
    return new CropAvatar($('#crop-avatar'));
  });

});
```

This is index.html

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta http-equiv="x-ua-compatible" content="ie=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <meta name="description" content="A complete example of Cropper.">
  <meta name="keywords" content="HTML, CSS, JS, JavaScript, jQuery plugin, image cropping, image crop, image move, image zoom, image rotate, image scale, front-end, frontend, web development">
  <meta name="author" content="Fengyuan Chen">
  <title>Cropper</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="../../assets/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="../../dist/cropper.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/main.css">

  <!-- HTML5 shim and Respond.js for IE8 support of HTML5 elements and media queries -->
  <!--[if lt IE 9]>
    <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/html5shiv/3.7.2/html5shiv.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/respond/1.4.2/respond.min.js"></script>
  <![endif]-->
</head>

<body>
  <div class="container" id="crop-avatar">

    <!-- Current avatar -->
    <div class="avatar-view" title="Change the avatar">
      <img src="img/picture.jpg" alt="Avatar">
    </div>

    <!-- Cropping modal -->
    <div class="modal fade" id="avatar-modal" aria-hidden="true" aria-labelledby="avatar-modal-label" role="dialog" tabindex="-1">
      <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg">
        <div class="modal-content">
          <form class="avatar-form" action="crop.php" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post">
            <div class="modal-header">
              <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
              <h4 class="modal-title" id="avatar-modal-label">Change Avatar</h4>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
              <div class="avatar-body">

                <!-- Upload image and data -->
                <div class="avatar-upload">
                  <input type="hidden" class="avatar-src" name="avatar_src">
                  <input type="hidden" class="avatar-data" name="avatar_data">
                  <label for="avatarInput">Local upload</label>
                  <input type="file" class="avatar-input" id="avatarInput" name="avatar_file">
                </div>

                <!-- Crop and preview -->
                <div class="row">
                  <div class="col-md-9">
                    <div class="avatar-wrapper"></div>
                  </div>
                  <div class="col-md-3">
                    <div class="avatar-preview preview-lg"></div>
                    <div class="avatar-preview preview-md"></div>
                    <div class="avatar-preview preview-sm"></div>
                  </div>
                </div>

                <div class="row avatar-btns">
                  <div class="col-md-9">
                    <div class="btn-group">
                      <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-method="rotate" data-option="-90" title="Rotate -90 degrees">Rotate Left</button>
                      <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-method="rotate" data-option="-15">-15deg</button>
                      <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-method="rotate" data-option="-30">-30deg</button>
                      <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-method="rotate" data-option="-45">-45deg</button>
                    </div>
                    <div class="btn-group">
                      <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-method="rotate" data-option="90" title="Rotate 90 degrees">Rotate Right</button>
                      <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-method="rotate" data-option="15">15deg</button>
                      <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-method="rotate" data-option="30">30deg</button>
                      <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-method="rotate" data-option="45">45deg</button>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                  <div class="col-md-3">
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-block avatar-save">Done</button>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
            <!-- <div class="modal-footer">
              <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
            </div> -->
          </form>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <!-- /.modal -->

    <!-- Loading state -->
    <div class="loading" aria-label="Loading" role="img" tabindex="-1"></div>
  </div>

  <script src="../../assets/js/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="../../assets/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <script src="../../dist/cropper.min.js"></script>
  <script src="js/main.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Please include relevant parts of code in question. Thanks.

Comment: @Nicholas i did. thanks

Comment: Okay, good start, but as a moderator I would say that it looks like more code than you need to ask the question. It's better for both you and people looking at your question if you can reduce it to exactly the problem you are having. It's better for you because you might answer your own question before you post it, it's better for others because they don't have to do that for you and who wants to help with code you might have just copied from somewhere else? Thanks.

Answer (score 6):

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    // initial set up
    var $image = $('.cropper > img');
    var options = {
        aspectRatio: 16/9, // (1.7777)
        etc...,
        etc...
    };

    // initialize
    $image.cropper(options); 

    // toggle aspect ratio after initialization
    $(document).on('click', '#toggle-aspect-ratio .btn', function () {
        options.aspectRatio = $(this).attr('data-value'); 
        $image.cropper('destroy').cropper(options);
    });


</script>

<div id="toggle-aspect-ratio">
    <span class="btn" data-value="NaN">Freeform</span>
    <span class="btn" data-value="1.77777">16/9</span>
    <span class="btn" data-value="1.33333">4/3</span>
</div>
```

**Note:** $(this).attr('data-value') (or whatever) **must** be a number/decimal (eg: 1.33333) and **not** a string (eg: 4/3) or it will read as NaN.

Answer (score 4):

following code is to change the default setting --> for more details refer to Read.me file @ https://github.com/fengyuanchen/cropper.

```
    <script type="text/javascript">

     $.fn.cropper.setDefaults(
      {
       aspectRatio: 1, //// or 1.7777777777 (16/9) or any positive nubmer
      });

    </script>
```